# Заполнение промежуточной таблицы при связи многие ко многим

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Я в MS SQL Server создал 3 таблицы

```
table1
  idprod(автоинкремент)(ключевое)
  nameproduct

table2
  id(автоинкремент)(ключевое)
  idprod 
  idfabrica

table3
  idfabrica(автоинкремент)(ключевое)
  fabrica
```

Cвязал поля `idprod(table1)` <-> `idprod(table2)` и `idfabrica(table2)` <-> `idfabrica(table3)`

Потом в Visual Studio в Data Sources подключился к БД и перетащил на форму первую и третью табицы...

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы между ними связь работала? Промежуточная таблица не заполняется...

Comment: Похоже, вы считаете, что вторая таблица должна заполняться автоматически. Это не так.

Comment: почему? ведь там должны быть связующие индексы? или их надо вность вручную?
Просто при связи один ко многим индексы заполняются сами....

Comment: Скажу так. Вы заказываете одни товары, а вам присылают другие.
Ваша ситуация - таблица 1 - товары, таблица 2 - покупатели, и таблица 3 - связывающая их, т.е. товары, заказанные покупателями.
И что здесь автоматически заполняется?

Comment: т.е. при связи многие ко многим нужно именно самому заполнять эту промежуточную таблицу ?

Comment: Именно. Какой покупатель что купил.